# Drupal 7 drupal commerce single user multiple carts

Tags: php, drupal

Is there a way that I can make Drupal commerce's shopping cart kepp shopping carts 'per session'?

In the current scenario, all visitors are beeing loggedin as a single user. Let's not go into details as to why that is. It just IS. Naturally, they will all share one shopping cart. I'd like this cart to be "rememberd" by session not by "user account", effectively allowing the user to have completely separate carts in separate sessions.

Thank you.

### Solution:

In a custom module, implement `hook_commerce_cart_order_id()`, like so:

```
function mymodule_commerce_cart_order_id($uid = 0) {    
    $key = $uid . '-' . session_id(); 
    $carts = variable_get('mymodule_carts', array());
    if ( isset($carts[$key]) ) {
        return intval($carts[$key]);
    } else {
        // create a new cart for this session
        $order = commerce_cart_order_new($uid);
        $order->data['last_cart_refresh'] = REQUEST_TIME;
        $order_id = intval($order->order_id);

        // save the new order id to the module settings cache
        $carts[$key] = $order_id;
        variable_set('mymodule_carts', $carts);

        return $order_id;
    }
}
```

We're basically storing the order id's per user / per session. If there is no cart for this user for this session, make one and use that.

Hope no one else has to suffer.

Comment: so your site is set up incorrectly, and you need to break other things to make it pretend that it wasn't set up wrong? why not fix the bad design that caused this problem in the first place?

Comment: Yes. Yes. And this is not an option for now. :)

Comment: @MarcB I know. I really do, it burns me up inside but right now it's patching stuff up. (A brand new, started from scratch version is on the way). Anyway I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to hack the module or code that displays carts. There would be some logic in there that does something like..

```
if($user->uid == 0){
  //show anonymous cart
}else{
  //show user cart
}
```

You would want to remove the if statement and only include the anonymous code.
If you want to make sure the module doesn't get overwritten on an update you'd need to also alter the .info file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. However this was not the right direction. I wasn't looking to handle anonymous carts. (Drupal commerce does that pretty well). In this hellish scenario, the same user needed to be able to be logged in multiple times and still maintain separate carts. Turns out the solution was to implement `hook_commerce_cart_order_id()` in a custom module, then just do the 'per session' logic there.

Comment: glad you found a solution.